# What size cd to burn Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Need recommendation on what cd to use to burn Ubuntu 12.04. I have 80 minute, 700MB discs, but I would get another size if it would make process easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The iso images are too large for a standard 700 mb CD. Many if not most people have started using flash (usb) drives as it is cheaper, faster, and just as easy to use a flash drive. I would personally use a 2 gb flash drive.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick